# How do I group by two variables in R and arrange them in the right order using ggplot?

Tags: r

Having trouble grouping by two variables and having a correct descending order.

I'm using a modified Iris df for this, This is my script:

```
iris_new <- iris %>% 
  mutate(number_petals = sample(1:10, size = 150, replace = TRUE))
```

```
iris_new %>% 
  group_by(number_petals, Species) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(Petal.Length, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n), by_group = TRUE) %>%
  head(25) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(number_petals,n),y=n,fill=factor(Species))) +
  xlab("Number of Petals")+
  ylab("Total sum of petal lenghts") +
  geom_col() #+ coord_flip()
```

[image]

Two issues with this:

1. It does not sort by descending ever since I added the second group_by argument (Species).
2. Head(25) doesn't take the 25 highest sum of petal lengths per number_petals and per species. It takes the 25 highest petal lengths, agnostic of number_petals and Species.

I read that summarise() removes the second group_by variable, but I am not sure what to do with that information.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `factor`ed approach -

We create two new columns `n` and `n1` where `n1` is `sum` of `n` values in each `number_petals`. `arrange` the data by `n1` and create factor levels according to their occurrence. This `factor` level will ensure the order of the bars.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris_new %>% 
  group_by(Species, number_petals) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(Petal.Length, na.rm=TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(number_petals) %>%
  mutate(n1 = sum(n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(n1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(number_petals = factor(number_petals, unique(number_petals))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=number_petals,y=n,fill=Species)) +
  xlab("Number of Petals")+
  ylab("Total sum of petal lengths") +
  geom_col()
```

[image: chart without head fix]

`head(25)` would select first 25 rows irrespective of the grouping. If you want to select top rows by group looking into `?slice_max` or `?slice` in general.

---

To select top `n` (5 here) values here's a different approach using a join.

```
iris_new %>% 
  group_by(number_petals) %>%
  summarise(n=sum(Petal.Length, na.rm=TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
  slice_max(n, n = 5) %>%
  inner_join(iris_new %>% 
  group_by(Species, number_petals) %>%
  summarise(n1=sum(Petal.Length, na.rm=TRUE), .groups = "drop"), 
            by = 'number_petals') %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  mutate(number_petals = factor(number_petals, unique(number_petals))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=number_petals,y=n1,fill=Species)) +
  xlab("Number of Petals")+
  ylab("Total sum of petal lengths") +
  geom_col()
```

[image: sorted chart]

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks a ton - that was very helpful! Any chance you could help me add the slice() function? Tried slice(1:20) multiple places, including after arrange(), but I can't seem to get it to work (been trying for an hour now)... I feel like it has to happen after the last mutate(), but that doesn't seem right either.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: For which group do you want the first 20 rows? Note that none of the group has 20 rows in your example.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I'm using confidential data. I want the twenty (or 10, 5, doesn't matter) rows that have the highest "Total sum of petal lengths". So they should be grouped by "number of petals", but be able to be divided into "species" as is currently the case. Basically, I want a slice() function added, so that the graph above only shows the first, lets say 5, rows (number of petals 1, 9, 4, 8, 5). Would be great if its a slice(xx) functions so that I can customise the number of rows I want to show.

I am working on another confidential dataset, hence the confusion. 

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @DavidFærgeman Check the updated answer. This is probably closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: You're a legend - thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi Ronak. Actually, somehow the value has changed. As you can see from the graphs, 'total sum of petal lengths' has somehow tripled! Any idea what caused this?

Comment: Yeah, sorry! Had to use `n1` instead of `n` there. Fixed it.